# Get html file using jQuery then append something on the content before passing it to PHP

Tags: php, jquery, html

here is something I'm doing:

1. Get html file
2. Append a form inside that file
3. Pass the updated html to PHP using ajax
4. In the PHP file, create a new html file using the content passed

I'm doing it in the code like this:

---

JQUERY

```
jQuery.get(url_link, function(html){
    var form = "<form>OTHER FORM FIELDS HERE</form>"
    jQuery(html).find('#form_div').append(form);

    //Create new file using the updated html
    jQuery.ajax({
        method: "post",
        url: "custom.php",
        data: {
            'html': html
        }
    });
});
```

PHP

```
$html = $_POST['html'];
file_put_contents('new_file.html', $html);
```

But this one has a problem, the file is being created with the original content from the "url_link" but the form is not appending. If I pass jQuery(html) to ajax post instead, I am getting an error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation

Kindly help please. Thank you!

Comment: jquery(html) is an object, not a string